# pass entry value from one class to another class tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to pass entry values from one class to another using the get() method and i dont know how. Thanks in advance

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.x=tk.StringVar()
        self.y=tk.StringVar()
        self.key=tk.IntVar()
        self.key.set(0)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, LoggedIn, Balance):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Banking Application", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="User Login",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Create Account",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
```

This is from where i want to pass the userid entry value to Balance class

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller



        label = tk.Label(self, text="Login Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        #user id entry block
        tk.Label(self,text="UserID").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=4)
        self.userid=tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.controller.x)
        self.userid.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=6)
        #password entry block
        tk.Label(self,text="Password").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=4)
        self.password=tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.controller.y)
        self.password.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=6)

        self.submit=tk.Button(self, text="SUBMIT",
                           command=self.login)
        self.submit.pack();


        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Main Menu",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
    def getname(self):
        name=self.controller.x.get()
        print (name)
        return name
    def login(self):
        getname(self);
        for x in range(0,listsize):
            if(self.controller.x.get()==files[x]):
                print("welcome %s"%(self.controller.x.get()))
                if(self.controller.y.get()==keys[x]):
                    bal=open(self.controller.x.get()+'.txt','r')

                    currbal=int(bal.read())
                    print("login success")
                    self.controller.key.set(1)
                   # print(self.controller.key=1)
                    self.controller.show_frame("LoggedIn");
                    break
        else:
                print("Invalid credentials")
```

How to pass userid from pageone to this class

```
class Balance(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Balance Enquiry", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


        username = PageOne.getname(self);
        print(username)
        if(self.controller.key==1):
            print(username)
            bal=open(username+'.txt','r')
            currbal=int(bal.read())
            label1 = tk.Label(self, text=currbal)
            label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
###########


        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the savings page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("LoggedIn"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. When do you want to pass the contents of the Entry from one class to another? Specify better what you're trying to do with your code.

Comment: @nbro i am trying to pass the entry value which will be username entered by the user from pageone class to balance class where i will use the username to open a file named under that user